# Proving $\vec{x}=\frac{\vec{u}+\vec{v}}{\vert\vec{u}+\vec{v}\vert}=\frac12\sec\frac\alpha2(\vec{u}+\vec{v})$

Tags: vectors

> Prove:
> $$\vec{x}=\frac{\vec{u}+\vec{v}}{\vert\vec{u}+\vec{v}\vert}=\frac12\sec\frac\alpha2(\vec{u}+\vec{v})$$
> where $\vec{x}$ is the unit vector bisecting two non-coplanar unit vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ with angle $\alpha$ between them.

Comment: do you know how to relate angles and dot products ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just have to prove
$$
|{\vec{u} + \vec{v}}| = 2\cos\frac{\alpha}{2} .
$$
As $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are unit vectors, $|\vec{u}| = |\vec{v}| = 1$. Therefore,
$$
|{\vec{u} + \vec{v}}|^{2} = |\vec{u}|^2 + 2 \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} + |\vec{v}|^2 \\
= 2+ 2\cos \alpha = 4 \cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2} .
$$
Then, we obtain
$$
|{\vec{u} + \vec{v}}| = 2\cos\frac{\alpha}{2} .
$$